# Make do-while loop after search the arraylist

Tags: java

Hello amazing people from stackoverflow!

I have some problems with my code. So I need a help, I want to make a do-while loop for whenever user type an input, the search function will find it through the arraylist and if it cant find, it will loop until found. This program is working, but it will print 2 times because of the search function. I need also storing the return value in search function to 'City scity'. So here is my main method

```
do{
    System.out.print("Choose City: ");
    inputCity = userinput.nextLine();
    City scity = search(cities, inputCity);
}while(search(cities, inputCity) == null);
```

I don't know what to put in condition for while. The user will type their city input and search(cities,inputCity) will find it. If its not found then user need to type again their city. Here is my searching function

```
public static City search(ArrayList<City> cities, String name) {
    String cityname = name.toUpperCase();
    for(City t : cities){
        if(t.getNAME().equals(cityname)){
            System.out.println("You choose " + cityname);
            return t;}
    return null;
}
```

So, I want to know what the best solution to put in the while condition to make it works fine.

Comment: just do a while loop and break when the search method is not null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So why *do* you perform the same search twice?  There is no need.  If you don't need to retain the search result past the end of the loop, then perform the search *only* in the `while` clause:

```
do {
    System.out.print("Choose City: ");
    inputCity = userinput.nextLine();
} while (search(cities, inputCity) == null);
```

If you did need to retain the result past the end of the loop then you would need to declare `scity` outside and before the loop anyway.  In that case, after performing the search in the loop body *and storing the result*, all you need to do is refer to that stored result:

```
City scity;
do {
    System.out.print("Choose City: ");
    inputCity = userinput.nextLine();
    scity = search(cities, inputCity);
} while (scity == null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably what you want to do is:

```
City scity = null;
while(scity == null){
    System.out.print("Choose City: ");
    inputCity = userinput.nextLine();
    City scity = search(cities, inputCity);
}
// Do something with this city
```

This way scity can be used after exiting the loop.